# rsync will not delete files in subfolder, but does if subfolder is removed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

So I have an rysync script to move my media from one place to another.  Works really well, but I just recently realized that it is not deleteing files on the destination in the way I would expect.

If I have `/tv/<show/<season>/<episodes.file>` on the source it will copy that over just fine.

If I go back and delete the  or  directories, the deletions carry over to destination.

But if I only delete  be it one episode or many, it does not carry over the deletions.

Here's my rysnc command:

```
rysnc -avph --compress-level=9 --del  --partial  -e ssh <user@sourceIP:/media/video/tv/ /media/video/tv
```

I've also tried `--delete & --delete-after`. Prefer `-after` just so that if the copy gets interrupted I haven't deleted anything yet.

Comment: This question is suited better for Super User. I'm trying to migrate it for you.

Comment: The `-n` or `--dry-run` option is your friend. It allows you to change/test options without actually writing anything. You are probably looking for `rsync -uav --delete /path/to/src /path/to/dest` and remember, the trailing `/` matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea that you preserve ownership, permissions and date stamps over the backups also. I think the first reason rsync could fail do make deletes will be probably permission issues (like if you changed permission on the destination directory after first rsync execution). This works for me as expected maintaining an exact mirror in the backup: 'rsync -avlpEXogtz --delete ./test/ ./test2/' This works also over the network using ssh. Check these options on the manpage. Adding the option -n will perform a dry-run for testing purposes not changing files.